# Including header file generated using configure.ac

Tags: linux, configuration, compilation, makefile

My configure scripts generates a headerfile which contains the macros defined in the configure.ac. In order to use that macros I have to include the header file in my source code. Is there any way that configure generated header file gets included in every source file automatically?

Comment: Add `-include file` to your preprocessor flags.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example on how to add it?

Comment: It depends, one way would be to add `AM_CPPFLAGS = -include file` to your Makefile.am.